# How to clear float in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use the following code, but it seems can not clear the *float*.

How to clear or close the pull-float or how to correctly use left-float and right-float in Bootstrap v3?

> `
>
> text
>
> 网站导航
>
> |
>
> 人才招聘
>
> |
>
> 企业邮箱
>
> |
>
> 旗下公司

`

Comment: Where do you want to clear the float?

Comment: the container doesn't need a clearfix it's already got that by default in Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="pull-left"><a href="">text</a></div>
      <div class="pull-right">...</div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The .container and .container fluid is already cleared in Bootstrap.